# Tensorflow convert predicted values to binary

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow

I created a neural network that is supposed to classify a person as either making more than 50k or less. When I output a prediction, I get values like [ 2.06434059 -2.0643425 ]. But I need them to be in [1, 0] or [0, 1]. Is there any tensorflow function that will convert the predictions, or do I have to do it manually?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about the argmax command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the softmax of your output. eg.

```
output = tf.nn.softmax(input)
```

It will convert the values to a probability distribution where the values will sum to one.

Otherwise if you just want {1,0} just take the max of the values coming in.